# How to add html code after a </style> tag using a shell script?

Tags: html, bash, shell

its been a few hour that i tried to insert html code after a tag.
I cant find a good way to do it. Any idea? I have been suggested sed (i am working on it).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, show us what you tried and an input/outpu example

Answer (score 0):

Ed can do this.

```
cat >> htmlinsert.ed << EOF

/\/style/
a
<p>This is some HTML code.</p>
.
wq
EOF

ed -s file.html < htmlinsert.ed
```